# How to get enum from Android in Unity

Tags: c#, android, enums, unity-game-engine

I am trying to retrieve the enum from [Bitmap.CompressFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html). What ever I am trying, I cannot seem to access the class. Has anyone done this before?

**Code:**

```
...

AndroidJavaClass bitmapClass = new    AndroidJavaClass("android.graphics.Bitmap");
AndroidJavaClass bitmapCompressEnum = bitmapClass.Get<AndroidJavaClass>("CompressFormat");

...

bitmap.Call("compress", bitmapCompressEnum.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("PNG"), 100, fileOutputStreamObject);
```

**Error:**

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no
>   "Ljava/lang/Class;" field "CompressFormat" in class
>   "Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;" or its superclasses
>                                             java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/Class;" field "CompressFormat" in class
>   "Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;" or its superclasses

Comment: Because Enum isn't a class. You want to get the values of the enum and not a class

Answer (score 1):

```
AndroidJavaClass bitmapClass = new    AndroidJavaClass("android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat");
bitmapClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("PNG");
```

Try this.
in order to solve the same problem, it took three hours to find a solution.
The solution is to write a java demo to print out the `Bitmap.CompressFormat` path, print the result is `android.graphics.Bitmap $ CompressFormat`
[tucao in my mother tongue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naF6o.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.